# GCC cannot find static library

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, static-linking, configure

I was trying to build strongswan staticlly.  I compiled openssl static library in a non-standard lib directory.  I added `-static` to CFLAGS, and `-L<path_to_static_library>` to LDFLAGS in ./configure step.  However, it still said

```
checking for EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new in -lcrypto... no 
configure: error: OpenSSL libcrypto not found
```

**Question:**
1. Is there anything wrong with the parameter?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you do `./configure --help` to list all command-line options, does it list any to provide a path to the SSL library? And note that this path should not be the path to the actual library-file itself, but to the directory where the library can be found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does not contain options to specify ssl library path and -L path is the directory contains openssl static library.

Comment: There should be a file called `config.log` -- it is supposed to contain every information to find out what the problem was (mind you, to do it you have to have some programming knowledge).

Comment: Thank you so much sir, according to the log, the real issue is pthread is not linked, the error info is so misleading!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt again, I built the software yesterday, however I run ldd command, it still said it need libpthread.so...etc.  So, why is that?

Comment: @user762750 because you link with `-lpthread`

Comment: So what’s the correct command to static link library?

Comment: BTW, a log in config.log said "warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking".  Does it mean the program doesn't support static link?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/3349

```sh
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib \
    --with-ipsecdir=/usr/sbin \
    --with-ipseclibdir=/usr/lib/strongswan \
    --with-capabilities=native \
    --disable-defaults \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-monolithic \
    --enable-nonce \
    --enable-openssl \
    --enable-x509 \
    --enable-pkcs1 \
    --enable-vici \
    --enable-charon \
    --enable-ikev2 \
    --enable-swanctl \
    --enable-kernel-netlink \
    --enable-socket-default
```